# How come I can use a packages method when it says it belongs to a different type?

Tags: go

Sorry for the horrible horrible title, first off if anybody can offer an edit for a better title after reading my question please, submit it, I'm pretty bad with my terminology at the moment.

So, simple question:

Reading through the `net/http` package on how to make `http.Get` requests and it says all I have to do is

`resp, err := http.Get(blah)`

Ok fair enough so scrolling down the list to see what parameters this `Get` function took, I couldn't find it directly under the functions of the http package

So scrolling down I find a `Get` method under `type Client`

So how come I don't have to first `http.Client` then make my `Get` request to that? Just a little confused. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two different versions of the method. In one case; `http.Get` it's defined at the package level, this works much like a static method in C# or Java. In the other it has a receiver of type `http.Client` it's more like an instance method on that type in C# or Java. The type `http.Client` is as you'd expect in the same package.

package level get:
http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get

```
 func Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
    //^ absence of receiver = package scoped
    //^ uppercase method name so it is 'exported' which is about like public
```

client receiver get:
http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get

```
   func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
        //^ this is the receiver
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where in the documentation can I see the version that's implemented at the package level, or did I miss it.

Comment: @Datsik here's a link to it in the normal docs http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get from there you can also click the method to go to the actual source http://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=9055:9103#L265 here's the clients get http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get